# create a dictionary for letters

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been trying to build a function to get letter frequencies from a string and store them in a dictionary.

I have done something like that :

```
s="today the weather was really nice"

def get_letter_freq(s):
    for letter in(s):
        x=letter.split()
    f=dict()
    for each_letter in x:
        if f.has_key(x):
                   f[x]+=1
        else:
                    f[x]=1
print f
```

Could you help me put things into order and find my mistakes?

Why I get an error that my 'f' is not defined?

Comment: the variable f is defined only inside the function get_letter_freq (it's called the scope of the variable.

Comment: You should look into [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the collections module.

Answer (score 3):

Besides that indentation  error your program has many other problems, like:

```
s = "today the weather was really nice"

def get_letter_freq(s):
    f = dict()
    for each_letter in s:      #you can directly iterate over a string, so no need of split()
        if each_letter in f:   #has_key() has been deprecated
            f[each_letter]+=1   
        else:
            f[each_letter]=1
    return f                 #better return the output from function

print get_letter_freq(s)
```

By the way `collections.Counter()` is good for this purpose:

```
In [61]: from collections import Counter

In [62]: strs = "today the weather was really nice"

In [63]: Counter(strs)
Out[63]: Counter({' ': 5, 'e': 5, 'a': 4, 't': 3, 'h': 2, 'l': 2, 'r': 2, 'w': 2, 'y': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'i': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 's': 1})
```

Answer (score 3):

- In your code, your first for loop, where you have your `letter.split()` statement seems useless. Why you want to split a single character, you get in your loop?
- Secondly, you have defined your `f = dict()` inside your function and
  using it ouside. It will not be visible outside.
- Third, your should not use `f.has_key`. Just do, `key in my_dict` to
  check for availability of key in dict.
- And at last, you can pass your dictionary as parameter to your
  function. Then modify it there, and finally return it. (Although you can also do it without passing the `dict` in your function. just create a new one there, and return it).
- So, in your code, almost everything is fine. You just need to remove your first for loop in function, and move `f = dict()` outside the function, before invoking it. And pass it as a paramter.

### Way 1:

So, you can rather try the following modified code of yours: -

```
def get_letter_freq(my_dict, s):
    for letter in s:
        if letter in my_dict:
            my_dict[letter] += 1
        else:
            my_dict[letter] = 1

    return my_dict

my_dict = dict()
my_str = "today the weather was really nice"
print get_letter_freq(my_dict, my_str)
```

---

### Way 2: -

Alternatively, you can also use a pre-defined library function [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections#collections.Counter) from [`collections`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections), which does exactly what you want.

---

### WAY 3: -

As suggested by `@thebjorn` in comment, you can also use `defaultdict`, which will make your task easier, in that, you won't have to check for the availability of `key` in dictionary before adding it. The count will automatically default to `0`: -

```
from collections import defaultdict
def get_letter_freq(s):
    my_dict = defaultdict(int)

    for letter in s:
        my_dict[letter] += 1  

    return my_dict

my_str = "today the weather was really nice"
print list(get_letter_freq(my_str).items())
```

Comment: Excellent advice, but why would you pass the dict as an argument? (I would also suggest using `defaultdict`, or `dict.setdefault`, if not using `collections.Counter`).

Comment: @thebjorn.. Well, passing dict is exactly not needed, but if there is a need to use it somewhere outside, then it would be a more readable way. Looks clear that we are modiying the dictionary that we passed.

Answer (score 1):

1. `f` is defined inside `get_letter_freq`, you can't access it from outside.
2. Your function should `return` the constructed dictionary.
3. You should actually **call** the function.
4. What do you expect from splitting a single letter? Just leave that part out, and you don't need the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

`print f` needs to be indented, if it has to be part of get_letter_freq.
& f does not exist outside get_letter_freq. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
s="today the weather was really nice"
print dict([ ( letter, s.count(letter)) for letter in string.lowercase[:25]])
```

If case sensitivity is important use `s.lower().count(letter)` instead.